# PyTorch backpropagation is too slow by custom loss

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I'm currently implementing a custom contrastive loss for the network but the training process is very slow. I investigate this problem and finally find that the backpropagation of the custom loss makes the main contribution to the problem.

Here is the simplified code.

```py
n = 2000
neighbors = 2
x = torch.randn((n, n), requires_grad=True)

start = time.time()
row_sum = torch.sum(torch.exp(x), dim=1) - torch.exp(torch.diagonal(x, 0))
y = torch.zeros((n, neighbors))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(neighbors):
        y[i][j] = x[i][random.randrange(0, n)]
loss = torch.sum(-torch.log(torch.exp(y) / row_sum.view(-1, 1)))  # Using broadcasting
print('Forward time: {:.3f}'.format(time.time() - start))

start = time.time()
loss.backward()
print('Backward time: {:.3f}'.format(time.time() - start))
```

The results is below.

```
Forward time: 0.255
Backward time: 37.502
```

The backward time depends on `n` and `neighbors`. When `n = 1000` and `neighbors = 2`.

```
Forward time: 0.241
Backward time: 9.094
```

When `n = 3000` and `neighbors = 2`.

```
Forward time: 0.250
Backward time: 136.768
```

When `n = 2000` and `neighbors = 1`.

```
Forward time: 0.124
Backward time: 22.925
```

When `n = 2000` and `neighbors = 3`.

```
Forward time: 0.210
Backward time: 58.341
```

Is there a way to speed up the performance?

Answer (score 0):

As [@Flavia Giammarino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11989081/flavia-giammarino) mentions, avoiding the loops can speed up the backward time. [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) function do the correct sampling for the problem.

```py
>>> t = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> torch.gather(t, 1, torch.tensor([[0, 0], [1, 0]]))
tensor([[ 1,  1],
        [ 4,  3]])
```

The final code is below.

```py
import time
import torch

n = 2000
neighbors = 2
x = torch.randn((n, n), requires_grad=True)
random_nbrs = torch.randint(low=0, high=n, size=(n, neighbors))

start = time.time()
row_sum = torch.sum(torch.exp(x), dim=1) - torch.exp(torch.diagonal(x, 0))
y = torch.gather(x, 1, random_nbrs)
loss = torch.sum(-torch.log(torch.exp(y) / row_sum.view(-1, 1)))
print('Forward time: {:.3f}'.format(time.time() - start))

start = time.time()
loss.backward()
print('Backward time: {:.3f}'.format(time.time() - start))

# Forward time: 0.010
# Backward time: 0.037
```